# Runtime Error Processing WASM in ``` std::stof```?

Tags: eosio-code, wasm, c++

```
        [[eosio::action]]
        void hi(){
            string strNum;
            strNum.push_back('3');
            float currNum = std::stof(strNum);//  
            print("currNum=",currNum);
        }
```

then

```
MacBook-Plou:testkeys treaser$ cleos push action fy hi '[]' -p testhero@active
Error 3070002: Runtime Error Processing WASM
Error Details:
wabt execution failure (out of bounds memory access)
pending console output:
```

Comment: Please add a decent description about what you are trying to do.

Comment: he's obviously trying to parse a string containing a number into a float

Comment: @Lou, I have this same issue.  did you solve it?

Comment: this seems important enough for me to report it as a bug on github: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/404

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make that happen either but I did make this work:

```
std::string s("limit: 686.97");
float limit = atoi(s.c_str());
printf("limit [%f]\n", limit);
```

*** Edit I ***

of course, that gets us to integer. sadly the atof is not available, so I think counting the number of digits in the string, removing the dot, converting to an integer and then dividing by the number of digits would give the correct value. bloody mess

```
float _stof(std::string s)
{   
    std::size_t i = s.find(".");
    int digits = s.length() - i - 1;
    s.erase(i, 1);
    return atoi(s.c_str()) / pow(10, digits);
}
```